# Using Audio HTML5 tag in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, audio

I am trying to have multiple audio HTML5 elements using ng-repeat in Angular JS. While the audio elements(HTML5) are rendering, and the first one plays (using the controls of the HTML5 audio element) but the remaining are **disabled**. See image below (the volume controls are all coming as disabled and the audio file doesn't play either):
[image]

I am using the following code:

**HTML**

```
...
          <md-card ng-repeat="item in audio.items">
            <md-card-content>
              <audio controls id="{{item.id}}">
                <source ng-src="{{item.link}}"></source>
              </audio>
              <button ng-click="playAudio(item.id)">Play</button>
              </md-card-content>
          </md-card>     
...
```

**JS**

```
...
$scope.audio = {
  items = [{id: "audio0", link: "static/audio/content1.mp3"},
    {id: "audio1", link: "static/audio/content2.mp3"}]
  };

$scope.playAudio = function(id) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(audio);
    audio.play();
 };
...
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console. I'm running python -m SimpleHTTPServer. Could it be something to do with the webserver being single-threaded?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds plausible. Have you tried running this piece of code an a local server with apache or something -> Wampserver

Comment: Could you upload an example to jsfiddle?